# Cant get distinct value from table

Tags: mysql, distinct

[my table photo][1]

**By this**

```
SELECT distinct(weight), id, product_id, value2 FROM `modx_msop2_price` order by product_id, weight
```

**I Get this**

```
0.08    939 500 black
0.08    748 500 redgold
0.08    748 500 maze
0.50    720 500 redgold
0.50    744 500 olimpgold
10.00   910 440 med
10.00   920 440 green
10.00   942 440 blue

...
```

*"product_id" have all weight values.*

**I wanna something like this this**

```
SELECT distinct(weight), id, product_id, value2 FROM `modx_msop2_price`
```

**Result table should look like this:**

```
0.80    939 440 black
10.00   910 440 med
20.00   379 440 grafit
0.08    748 500 redgold
0.50    744 500 olimpgold
...
```

*so "product_id" have only distinct "weight" values*

***The solution was using «GROUP BY»***
    select weight,product_id,id,value2 from modx_msop2_price **group by product_id,weight** order by product_id

Comment: Your question is not well formed because you never really gave the logic used to arrive at your expected result set.  For example, how do you end up with just one weight `748` ?

Comment: Tim, edited the table column postion. Missed it at first.

Comment: You never answered my question.  How do you end up with one `748` in the result set?

Comment: You never answered my question.  How do you end up with one `748` in the result set?

Comment: Tim, 748 duplicated when i've wrote the message

Answer (score 0):

If one product id is required, it can be grouped in MYSQL which gives the first id.
Note: Below query will produce an error in Orcale but will give output for MYSQL.

Query goes like:

SELECT id, product_id, value2,wight
FROM `modx_msop2_price`
GROUP BY id 
order by product_id, weight;

Comment: Not this one.
Require id where product_id has distinct weight.
In this case

0.80 ---939 - 440 - black
10.00 - 910 - 440 - med
20.00 - 379 - 440 - grafit

product_id = 440 have this "weight" values 0.8, 10, 20,
next product_id = 500 should get "weight" distinct values 0.50 and 0.08

so the lines doesnt duplicate with another
0.50 - 984 - 500 - colorName

Comment: If it has to be unique as per product id,weight then, group by the same.
Query goes here:

SELECT id, product_id, value2,weight FROM modx_msop2_price GROUP BY product_id,weight order by product_id, weight;

Answer (score 0):

Your required output seems 'inconsistent', but anyway you can try this

```
SELECT weight, id, product_id, value2 FROM `modx_msop2_price` group by     
product_id order by product_id, weight;
```

OR

You can also group by 'weight'.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was **using «GROUP BY»**

```
select weight,product_id,id,value2 from modx_msop2_price group by product_id,weight order by product_id
```